# How do I get a "select count(*) group by" using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I would like to execute the follow sentence using laravel eloquent

```
SELECT *, count(*) FROM reserves  group by day
```

The only solution occurs to me is to create a view in the DB, but I am pretty sure there is a way to do it in laravel way.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$reserves = DB::table('reserves')->selectRaw('*, count(*)')->groupBy('day');
```

Comment: why does he could use this and why this could work for him?

Answer (score 5):

As you wish to do it with Laravel Eloquent I assume you have a model name `Reserve`. In this case you can use this

```
$reserve = Reserve::all()->groupBy('day')->count();
```

Comment: What if there's 10 million records?

Comment: Just to make sure everyone knows: This is a usable solution **but** the grouping happens in php after selecting and it is much faster to group in the sql statement.

Comment: @Okneloper pagination probably

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
#Laravel Raw Expressions

  $reserves = DB::table('reserves')
                       ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as reserves_count'))           
                       ->groupBy('day')
                       ->get();

OR

  $reserves = Reserve::select(['reserves.*'])
                       ->groupBy('day')
                       ->count();
```

Further read [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

Comment: Could you explain a bit further your answer? It will be more helpful for the OP