# How to count the number of records with groupby result in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am getting stuck on this i want the count the number of records but it returns me wrong value every time .Here is my table:-

```
id  contributor_id  user_id     history_id  contributor_income 
1   1               14              1               0.57    
2   1               14              2               0.57    
3   1               14              3               0.57    
4   1               14              4               3.75    
5   2               14              5               0.57
```

Here above is my  table but it gives me count 4 but i want 2. Here is my query :-

```
$query  = DB::table('contributor_commissions')
          ->groupBy('contributor_id')->count();
```

But when i print this it gives count as 4 but there are only two groups of contributor_id

Comment: And how many rows are there in the resultset?

Comment: there are total 5 rows in the table right now and there are two groups of contributor_id but when i print the above query it gives me count 4

Comment: So echo out all the rows returned in that query, see what the are!

Comment: there are two rows only but i don't want to use the php count function to count the array i want to do with query builder

Comment: Yeah, one with count 4 and other with count 1 right? So the query works fine :)

Comment: yeah exactly you get it

Comment: what about distinct ?

Comment: @Shanukk if you have answer upload it

Comment: $users = DB::table('contributor_commissions')->distinct()->get(); try this

Comment: What do you want to get? I don't get it

Comment: @Nerea i want the count 2 only output is : 2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040965/laravel-5-3-distinct-count-using-eloquent-instead-of-query-builder

Comment: already answered...please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
DB::table('contributor_commissions')->distinct('contributor_id')->count('contributor_id');
```

Comment: i want count not get the array

Comment: change contributor_commissions to contributor_id

Comment: @kanumahajan it will work -anyway thanks dear for the correction

Answer (score 1):

This should work
    `DB::table('contributor_commissions')->distinct('contributor_id')->count()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$query = $user_info = DB::table('contributor_commissions')
                     ->select('contributor_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                     ->groupBy('contributor_id')
                     ->get();
```

Comment: don't want the array i want the count

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
$reserves = DB::table('contributor_commissions')->selectRaw('*, count(*)')->groupBy('contributor_id');
```

Comment: Its a copy & paste answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827917/how-do-i-get-a-select-count-group-by-using-laravel-eloquent

Why didn't you mark it duplicate or either give reference with the link

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Instead of user have to click and go there and find the code. What's wrong with this? Just copy code and use it in your's. So easy!! And I didn't copied this.